# Change background div on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use javascript to change the background and text of a div on hover. But I'm having some problems. Here's the code:

```css
.square1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.square2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="squares">
  <div class="square1">
    <p>I'm square1!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="square2">
    <p>I'm square2!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i want to do at the end is to make the first square appear as second square on hover. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why not use `:hover`in css

Comment: where is js code ?

Comment: you can use `:hover` in your css to change the background. alternatively, you can use the mouseover function for changing the background as well as the text

Comment: I have an assignment in school and i really need to use JavaScript. PS thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var w;
function a(e)
{
w=e.textContent;
e.textContent=document.querySelector('.square2 > p').textContent

}
function b(e)
{
e.textContent=w
}
```

```css
.square1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.square1:hover {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.square2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.square2:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="squares">
  <div class="square1" onmouseover='a(this)' onmouseout='b(this)'>
    <p>I'm square1!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="square2">
    <p>I'm square2!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.square1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.square1:hover {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.square2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.square2:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="squares">
  <div class="square1">
    <p>I'm square1!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="square2">
    <p>I'm square2!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The content is not changing

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
.square1:hover {
      background:blue;
      color:white;
      /* or any other props*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **Prince** or **Maheer Ali** mentioned, that way; and if you want have it nicer with fade effect add into CSS:

```
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
```